# SQL statement to join tables - Nothing is working

Tags: sql, httpcontext

This statement is extracting a list to excel which works fine

```
string sql = "select wo.email, wo.productid, wo.variantid ";
sql += "from woeosemails wo ";
sql += "order by email, productid ";

string attachment = "attachment; filename=EmailList.csv";
HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");

HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("email,productid,variantid");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DB.GetDBConn()))
{
conn.Open();
using (IDataReader NotifyReader = DB.GetRS(sql, conn))
{
while (NotifyReader.Read())
{
string email = DB.RSField(NotifyReader, "email");
int productid = DB.RSFieldInt(NotifyReader, "productid");
int variantid = DB.RSFieldInt(NotifyReader, "variantid");

email = email.Replace("\"","\"\"");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("\"" + email + "\"," + productid.ToString() + "," + variantid.ToString());
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(Environment.NewLine);

}
}
conn.Close();
}

HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

I've tried adding a variety and I thought that this would work

I want to add two columns from another sql table, these are Name and SKU. Any ideas on how I can modify the first part of this code, I have tried joining the tables but nothing seems to work. The closest I have is modifying the first part to this

```
string sql = "select wo.email, wo.productid, wo.variantid,  p.Name pname,  p.Name psku, ";
        sql += "from woeosemails wo ";
                    sql += "join Product p with (nolock) on p.ProductID = wo.productid ";
        sql += "order by email, productid ";
```

Any help would be great

Comment: What is the error you're getting? You could try to use "inner join" instead of "join"? http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: The order by could be messing this up, you have two ProductID's, so you need to specify which one, ie: wo.productid.  Check the same for email too.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to put alias to your order by properties and remove the comma at first line at the end. Try following:

```
string sql = "select wo.email, wo.productid, wo.variantid,  p.Name pname,  p.Name psku ";
sql += "from woeosemails wo ";
sql += "join Product p with (nolock) on p.ProductID = wo.productid ";
sql += "order by wo.email, wo.productid ";
```

Comment: Getting this error Compiler Error Message: CS0128: A local variable named 'variantid' is already defined in this scope

Comment: file is now running but the additional two columns are not being outputted. but gives me an indication of where I am going. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

The order by could be messing this up, you have two ProductID's, so you need to specify which one, ie: wo.productid. Check the same for email too.